# get some of the items in an array

Tags: java, arrays, pointers

I have an array that contains integers and i want to filter this array based on the value like i want to get only items that is bigger than the last item by 30 or whatever

That's want i mean i have an array like this `[0,10,25,30,55,60,65,75,82....]`
and i want to filter this to have the first number and see if the next number is bigger by 30 if not jump on the next one and check

That what i have tried but i don't think its any closer to what i want

```
for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){
    if(array.get(i)<array.get(i+1)+30){
        //do something with that number
    }
}
```

Comment: Cab you please give expected output for example you mentioned

Comment: Do you have an array (`int[]` or `Integer[]`) or a collection of integers, like a `List<Integer>` or a `Set<Integer>`? You are checking `i < array.size()`, but `.size()` is not a method of an array but one of a `List`.

Comment: @deHaar why does it matter ?

Comment: @swapnap i want my array [0,32,35,64,83,95,..] to be like that [0,32,64,95... ]

Comment: @R3ter it doesn't matter much in this case, I just wanted to know because I like things to be exact and those data structures are different and need to be handled differently, in some cases at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You should keep track of the last number you processed, and compare it to the next number.

```
int current = array.get(0);
//do something with that number
for (int i=1; i<array.size(); i++) {
    if (array.get(i) >= current + 30) {
        //do something with that number
        current = array.get(i);
    }
}
```